# Show data from database depending on selected option in a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using a drop down list and I want to show the content on a table in the same page depending on the selected item in the list.

The data for this table is retrieved from a database using SQL. I want to show only the data where the 'canal' column from the database is equal to the selected item from the drop down list.

This is my code in PHP:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<form name='choose-channel'>

<select name='channel'>
        <option selected='true' disabled='true'> Choose one channel </option>
        <option value='Option-1'> Option-1 </option>
        <option value='Option-2'> Option-2 </option>
        <option value='Option-2'> Option-3 </option>
</select>

</form>

<?php

//Conect with the database
require_once 'conectar-database.php';

$query = "SELECT id_sku FROM database.table";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table border='1' >";

echo '<tr>';
echo    '<th> id_sku </th>';
echo '</tr>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['id_sku'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

?>

<body>

<body>

</html>
```

I wanted to put in the query something like this: 'WHERE channel = $channel', and this channel variable would have the value choosen from the drop down list. I think i need to do something with javascrip, but I don't know to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you adventured yourself over to the right, under "Related"? >>>

Comment: You need to use AJAX for the same

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you want to show data without refreshing the page, you need to use **[AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)**.
You can **[read](http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/ajax_post.asp)** more about **[AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)** so to get it's working.

I hope this will help you.

PHP View Page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#channel").change(function(){
    $.post( "ajax.php", { channel: $(this).val() })
     .success(function(data) {

             $(".result").html(data);
         });
   });
});
</script>
<select name='channel'>
   <option selected='true' disabled='true'> Choose one channel </option>
   <option value='Option-1'> Option-1 </option>
   <option value='Option-2'> Option-2 </option>
   <option value='Option-2'> Option-3 </option>
</select>
<div class="result"></div>
```

ajax.php (save in the location) :

```
    <?php

    //get value from page

    $channel = $_POST['channel'];
    //Conect with the database
            require_once 'conectar-database.php';

    $query = "SELECT id_sku FROM database.table where channel =$channel";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $msg ='';
    $msg = $msg." <table border='1' >";

    $msg = $msg. '<tr>';
    $msg = $msg.    '<th> id_sku </th>';
    $msg = $msg. '</tr>';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $msg = $msg. '<tr>';
            $msg = $msg. '<td>'.$row['id_sku'].'</td>';
        $msg = $msg. '</tr>';
    }

    $msg = $msg. '</table>';

    echo $msg;

    ?>
```